# Не отображается image на ImageView на реальном устройстве

Tags: android, kotlin

Имеется ImageView на котором я хочу показывать изображение

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView_logo"
     android:layout_width="117dp"
     android:layout_height="117dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
     android:onClick="@{() -> model.onClickImage()}"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_phone"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.475"
     android:visibility="visible"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo2"/>
```

На реальном устройстве у меня просто не показывается изображение, (либо сначала показывается, а затем пропадает).

Я уже испробовал многое.

Как устанавливаю:

```
private fun setDevImage() {
        context?.let {
            Log.d("Set", "dev image")
            Log.d("Width", imageLogo.width.toString())
            Log.d("Height", imageLogo.height.toString())
            Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isVisible.toString())
            Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isShown.toString())
//            imageLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_dev)
            imageLogo.setImageDrawable(
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                    it,
                    R.drawable.logo_dev
                )
            )
            Log.d("Width", imageLogo.width.toString())
            Log.d("Width", imageLogo.height.toString())
            Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isVisible.toString())
            Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isShown.toString())

        }

    }
```

Проблема еще в том, что на этом экране используется MotionLayout с несколькими состояниями. Но я вроде везде повесил логи, но так и не пойму почему оно не отображает (на эмуляторе все норм)

**Изменение состояния**

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        layout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout)

        layout.setTransition(R.id.end, R.id.login)
        layout.setTransitionDuration(1)
        layout.transitionToEnd()
    .....

    }
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        unregistrar = KeyboardVisibilityEvent.registerEventListener(activity) {
            if (it) {
                Log.d("Width", imageLogo.width.toString())
                Log.d("Width", imageLogo.height.toString())
                Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isVisible.toString())
                Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isShown.toString())
                layout.setTransition(R.id.login, R.id.showKeyboard)
                layout.setTransitionDuration(1)
                layout.transitionToEnd()
                Log.d("Width", imageLogo.width.toString())
                Log.d("Width", imageLogo.height.toString())
                Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isVisible.toString())
                Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isShown.toString())

                ...

                if (heightDiff < result) {

                    if (heightDiff < result - hLogo) {
                        Log.d("Width", imageLogo.width.toString())
                        Log.d("Width", imageLogo.height.toString())
                        Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isVisible.toString())
                        Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isShown.toString())
                        layout.setTransition(R.id.showKeyboard, R.id.visibleLogo)
                        layout.setTransitionDuration(1)
                        layout.transitionToEnd()
                        Log.d("Width", imageLogo.width.toString())
                        Log.d("Width", imageLogo.height.toString())
                        Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isVisible.toString())
                        Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isShown.toString())
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Width", imageLogo.width.toString())
                        Log.d("Width", imageLogo.height.toString())
                        Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isVisible.toString())
                        Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isShown.toString())
                        layout.setTransition(R.id.showKeyboard, R.id.visibleImage)
                        layout.setTransitionDuration(1)
                        layout.transitionToEnd()
                        Log.d("Width", imageLogo.width.toString())
                        Log.d("Width", imageLogo.height.toString())
                        Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isVisible.toString())
                        Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isShown.toString())
                    }
                }


            } else {
                Log.d("Width", imageLogo.width.toString())
                Log.d("Width", imageLogo.height.toString())
                Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isVisible.toString())
                Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isShown.toString())
                layout.setTransition(layout.currentState, R.id.login)
                layout.setTransitionDuration(1)
                layout.transitionToEnd()
                Log.d("Width", imageLogo.width.toString())
                Log.d("Width", imageLogo.height.toString())
                Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isVisible.toString())
                Log.d("Visibility", imageLogo.isShown.toString())

            }
        }

        viewModel.getDev()
    }
```

**MotionLayoutScene**

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Constraints to apply at the start of the animation -->
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageView_logo"
            android:layout_width="234dp"
            android:layout_height="234dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_phone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.475"
            android:visibility="visible">
            <PropertySet android:alpha="0.0" />
        </Constraint>

        
    </ConstraintSet>

    <!-- Constraints to apply at the end of the animation -->
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageView_logo"
            android:layout_width="234dp"
            android:layout_height="234dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_phone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.475"
            android:visibility="visible">
            <PropertySet android:alpha="1.0" />
        </Constraint>


        

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/login" >
            
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageView_logo"
            android:layout_width="117dp"
            android:layout_height="117dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_phone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.47000003" >
            <PropertySet android:alpha="1.0" />
        </Constraint>

        
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageView_logo"
            android:layout_width="117dp"
            android:layout_height="117dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_phone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.475" >
            <PropertySet android:alpha="1.0" />
        </Constraint>

        

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/visibleImage">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_logo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_logo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_logo" />


        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageView_logo"
            android:layout_width="117dp"
            android:layout_height="117dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_phone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.475" >
            <PropertySet android:alpha="1.0" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_logo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_logo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_logo" />


        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_logo"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.007" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/login_phone"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_login"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/button_login"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.783" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/registration"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtReceiver"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.103" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/txtReceiver"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvCreateOrder"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/tvCreateOrder"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/visibleLogo">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_logo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_logo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_logo" />


        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/imageView_logo"
            android:layout_width="117dp"
            android:layout_height="117dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_phone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.475" >
            <PropertySet android:alpha="1.0" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_logo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_logo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_logo" />


        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_logo"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.007" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/login_phone"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_login"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/button_login"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.783" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/registration"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtReceiver"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.103" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/txtReceiver"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvCreateOrder"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/tvCreateOrder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Я уже потратил около 6 часов на работе на попытку исправить этот баг, но так и не могу понять в чем дело.

Изображение представляет собой png - файл размером не более 20KB

Замена на `android:src="@drawable/logo2"` не помогает

Update проблема именно в MotionScene, так как я заменил MotionLayout на ConstainLayout, удалил все анимации в коде, и у меня начало отображаться.

Осталось только разобраться в чем проблема